# No NgClass reaction to the function

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

I use a function in NgClass that uses an array filled in ngOnInit.

ngOnInit -> **prepareRezerwation()** create **colorRezerwation** veriable:

```
    this.nodeService.getRezerwations(this.minMax).subscribe(rezerwations => { 
    this.prepareRezerwation(rezerwations);
    //   this.functionsService.showRezerwation(post, this.openingHours);
      // this.showSpinner = false;
    }, error => {
       console.log("Connection problem")
    });
```

**html -> [ngClass]="setColor(1,i):**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="big">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="xunk-calendar-cell"></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [ngClass]="setColor(1,i)">Name</td>
</ng-container>
```

**setColor(1,i):**

```
  setColor(colIndex, rowIndex){
    this.colorRezerwation.position.forEach(arrayItem => {
      if(arrayItem.column === colIndex && arrayItem.row === rowIndex){
        return {'reservation': true}
      } 
    });
  }
```

When I skip the entire forEach return it works OK.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning your class variable inside the function to the forEach loop rather than to the setColor function.

```js
setColor(colIndex, rowIndex){
    this.colorRezerwation.position.forEach(arrayItem => {
      if(arrayItem.column === colIndex && arrayItem.row === rowIndex){
   -->  return {'reservation': true} <-- this does not return to setColor
      } 
    });
}
```

You need to declare and hold the variable outside of the forEach loop and return that:

```js
setColor(colIndex, rowIndex){
    let class;
    this.colorRezerwation.position.forEach(arrayItem => {
      if(arrayItem.column === colIndex && arrayItem.row === rowIndex){
        class = {'reservation': true}
      } 
    });
    return class;
  }
```